# SharePoint Online User Profile updating

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile-service

Is there a REST API for updating User Profiles?

I've found the one to read them, but can't seem to work out how to update them.

[User Profile Properties With REST API–SharePoint Office 365](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/user-profile-properties-with-rest-api-sharepoint-office-365/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update SingleValueProperty

```
function updateSingleValue(){
var Headers = {
        'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    };

    var aboutData = {
        'accountName': "i:0#.f|membership|user@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        'propertyName': 'AboutMe', //can also be used to set custom single value profile properties
        'propertyValue': 'A tech savvy and computer geek which lives by earning bread on computers, passes time by watching/sitcoms and playing games on computers, also a loving husband, father, brother, son and friend and most importantly trying to be human being :)'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetSingleValueProfileProperty",
        type: "POST",
        headers: Headers,
        data: JSON.stringify(aboutData),
        success:profileUpdateSuccess ,
        error: profileUpdateFail
    });

function profileUpdateSuccess(response){
    console.log(response);

}
function profileUpdateFail(jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqxr);

}
}
```

Updating Multi Value property

```
function updateMultiValue(){

var Headers = {
            'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=nometadata"
        };

        var aboutData = {
            'accountName': "i:0#.f|membership|user@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            'propertyName': 'SPS-Skills', //can also be used to set custom single value profile properties
            'propertyValue': ["SharePoint", "Office 365", "Node JS", "Ionic", "Gsuite"]
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/SetMultiValuedProfileProperty",
            type: "POST",
            headers: Headers,
            data: JSON.stringify(aboutData),
            success:profileUpdateMultiSuccess ,
            error: profileUpdateMultiFail
        });



}

function profileUpdateMultiSuccess(response){
        console.log(response);

    }
    function profileUpdateMultiFail(jqxr, errorCode, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqxr);

    }
```

Hope this helps...Happy coding..!!!

Comment: Can I use above code to update User Profile Property value of other users?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set user profile properties using JSOM:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function(){
        SP.SOD.registerSod("sp.userprofiles.js", SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl("sp.userprofiles.js"));
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.userprofiles.js", "SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager", SetCurrentUserProperties);
    });

    var userProfileProperties;

    function SetCurrentUserProperties(){

        //Get Current Context   
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        //Get Instance of People Manager Class
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

        //Get properties of the current user
        userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();

        //Get only the accountname instead of all the properties. 
        clientContext.load(userProfileProperties, "AccountName");

        //Execute the Query.
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

            //Get the account name of the current user. It will be in the following format: "i:0#.f|membership|username@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com"
            var currentUserAccountName = userProfileProperties.get_accountName();

            //Set a single value property
            peopleManager.setSingleValueProfileProperty(currentUserAccountName, "AboutMe", "Value updated from JSOM!");

            //Set a multivalue property 
            var multipleValues = ["SharePoint", "Office 365", "Architecture"];
            peopleManager.setMultiValuedProfileProperty(currentUserAccountName, "SPS-Skills", multipleValues);

        //Execute the Query.
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

                console.log("properties updated!");
            }, 
            function(sender,args){
                //On Error
                console.log(args.get_message());
            });

        }, function(sender,args){
            //On Error
            console.log(args.get_message());
        });

    }
```

Reference:

[Set user profile properties using JSOM & JavaScript](https://www.vrdmn.com/2015/01/set-user-profile-properties-using-jsom.html)